# Change transaction isolation level for all queries

Tags: sql-server, transaction-isolation, ssms-2017

I am connecting to an SQL Server database with SSMS 2017 to check some errors in reports, and the DBA says that when I'm running heavy queries, it blocks the outgoing processes. So the solution is to set `transaction isolation level` to `read uncommited` or add `with (nolock)` in each query. My problem is that I'm running a lot of small queries, and sometimes I forget to add these sentences.

My question is, can I set `transaction isolation level` to `read uncommited` once and for all? Maybe there's an option in SSMS, or it can be set up for a specific user (me)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in 'Query Execution' section, shown in the image below. If you set this option on your PC ( SSMS), it will reflect just you.

[image]

Comment: I knew there should be something like this! Thanks for the quick and helpful answer!